# Не работает пауза в mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, listview, android-mediaplayer

Есть `MediaPlayer`, который воспроизводит музыку при нажатии на пункт ListView. Вот так. Код (+)

```
if (mediaPlayer == null){ mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); }
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
} 
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
try 
{
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(objects.get(posit));
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
}  catch (IOException e) {}

mediaPlayer.start();
```

Все работает, но если пересоздать список, то при нажатии на пункт музыка не останавливается, будет включается параллельно музыка.
Может это связано с тем, что `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer`; я объявляю глобальным.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я эту проблему решал так

1) Создал класс **[MyPlayer](https://github.com/mohaxspb/Odnako/blob/v3.0/src/ru/kuchanov/odnako/utils/MyPlayer.java)**, в нём сделал статический метод, возвращающий инициализированный объект **MediaPlayer**, общий для всего приложения. (вроде это называется синглтон).

```
public class MyPlayer
{
    static MediaPlayer mp;

    public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer()
    {
        if (mp == null)
        {
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        }

        return mp;
    }
}
```

2) Соответственно в коде получаю его так:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MyPlayer.getMediaPlayer();
```

Таким образом можно решить проблему создания множества экземпляров плееров.

**UPD_0:**

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816602/3212712) пишут, что ошибка из комментов вызвана тем, что MP не сброшен к начальному состоянию. Т.е. до setDataSource() надо вызвать reset().

Comment: Делаю так, первый раз(когда mp =null) работает дальше, - выбивает ошибку

Comment: А какую ошибку кидает? Думаю, она вызвана тем, что вы вызываете release() над плеером... Попробуйте убрать эту строку из своего кода.

Comment: Не знаю какую ошибку. Убрал release() все равно ошибка

Comment: Ну, посмотрите в logCat... Там будет написан тип ошибки и на какой строчке она выскочила.

Comment: Также у вас зря вызывается start() в конце кода. К этому моменту плеер ещё может быть не готов. Стартовать надо по событию, вызываемому в setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){ @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {}});

Comment: Выложыл лог ту .   http://vk.com/wall54842609_41

Comment: IllegalStateException в классе listAdapter на 150 строке. Что там?

Comment: try {
        150 .mediaPlayer.setDataSource(objects.get(posit));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
       }  catch (IOException e) {

       }

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: В чем проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите в конец моего ответа. После **UPD_0**

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло